# Intellij can't resolve Java packages

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to set up my Intellij plugin project on arch linux. 
Somehow intelliJ does not want to scan the dependencies.

I tried to use java 8 JDK, did not work. Invalidated caches.
Recreated the project.

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.0.4
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Illyria
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.6 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.6156.11, built on March 25, 2019
Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator
Expiration date: July 25, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b28 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.19.49-1-MANJARO
```

(The 2 Problems from the screenshots are from Python, which is somehow in several projects and I don't think this is related)

How can i fix this?

[image]
[image: Project JDK]
[image: Module Dependencies]

Comment: "JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b28 amd64" and "1.8.0_181"... where did it find "1.8.0_181"? I think something is amiss there.

Comment: That's the intellij about... dialog info. It's the builtin java version distributed within intellij

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong JDK configuration. Click the 'New...' button next to the JDK text box and configure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the plugin is built correctly from command line using Gradle but IntelliJ is unable to resolve dependencies on standard classes when I import the project.

I managed to find **only a workaround**. It worked with JDK 11. You can specify JDK 11 in IntelliJ, use it for development but you can still build the project form command line using the version you want.

You might also want to compare your configuration with the one I used [in my plugin](https://github.com/Shpota/twitter-plugin).